# The proof of the a set is countable by stating it is a countably infinite union of finite sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

> Let $S \subseteq$ R be the set of all real numbers $x$ with the property that there exists $n∈\mathbb N$ and integers $a_0,...,a_n∈\mathbb Z$, not all equal to zero, such that $a_0+a_1x+...+a_nx^n=0$
> Prove that the set S is countable. Use the lemma that a non-zero polynomial vanishes at only finitely many points.

Proof:
$\mathbb Z$ is countable, and thus the cartesian product of $\mathbb Z$ is still countable. Hence, $\mathbb Z^{n+1}$ is infinitely countable. Then let $P(\mathbb Z)$ be the set that contains all the polynomials except zero polynomial on $\mathbb Z$. Then there exists an isomorphism between $P(\mathbb Z)$ and $\mathbb Z^{n+1}$ by the coefficient in front of $x^0,x^1,...,x^n$.

Specifically, for any polynomial $a_0+a_1x+...+a_nx^n\in P(\mathbb Z)$, there exists an element $(a_0,...,a_n)\in \mathbb Z^{n+1}$, so there exists an isomorphism.

Thus, $P(\mathbb Z)$ is countably infinite. Then let all polynomials in  $P(\mathbb Z)$ equal to zero. By the lemma, there only exists finitely many zero points for any nonzero polynomial.

Thus set S is a countably infinite union of finite sets. As a result, S is countable.

Comment: You should rather count the zeroes of the polynomials. Also, $n$ should not be fixed.

Comment: $S$ is called the set of real algebraic numbers.  for fixed $n$, the set of all degree $n$ polynomials with integer coefficients is countable because $\mathbb{Z}^n$ is countable. Each polynomial of degree $n$ has at most $n$ real roots. try to finish it now